# What is the derivation of the word "double-dome"?

Tags: etymology

What's the derivation of the meaning of the word "double-dome," meaning intellectual?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard "double dome" used in a context where I took it to mean "military brass".

Answer (score 1):

It seem that it is just the image of a '[dome](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dome)' similar to a bald  head at the origin of the saying:

***[Double-dome](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-dome)***:

> - (slang) (mildly derogatory) Alternative spelling of doubledome An intellectual or scholar. (Wiktionary)

[Origin](http://www.yourdictionary.com/doubledome):

> - The word conjures the image of two bald-headed men putting their heads together in an effort to solve a problem.

According to [The Oxford Dictionary of American Political Slang](https://books.google.it/books?id=gxHiBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22doubledome%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIneW-2dmSyAIVQ1wUCh2uDgwi#v=onepage&q=%22doubledome%22&f=true) and the [The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=neVBmSyNRnEC&pg=PA311&dq=%22doubledome%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBmoVChMIneW-2dmSyAIVQ1wUCh2uDgwi#v=onepage&q=%22doubledome%22&f=true) the term was in use in the 40's in the US.

> - 1943 H.A. Smith Putty Knife Factory 207: Arthur Birsbane [ 1936]...was known among fellow newspapermen as Old Double Dome.

The term is a synonym of [egghead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276058/what-is-the-derivation-of-the-word-double-dome/276061#276061) where the reference to a bald head is similar.

> - 1907, "bald person," from egg (n.) + head (n.). Sense of "intellectual" is attested from 1918
> - presumably fr the putative high, ***domed***, egg-shaped heads of such persons; the term was used in a letter of Carl Sandburg about 1918]

[image: Cupola (dome) del Brubelleschi - Florence]

Cupola (dome)  del Brunelleshi - Florence